# ¿Como contar el numero de palabras de inputs dinámicos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una pantalla donde es generado inputs dinamicos, la cantidad de inputs depende de lo que contesto un usuario en una pantalla anterior. Para crear los inputs dinamicos utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
function autocompleteTextAreaAct2_ses5_1(){
const ax = [];
const ay = [];

var a = ["En primer lugar, asegúrate de que tengas suficiente tiempo para dormir. Con dormir lo suficiente cada noche, puedes sentirte mejor y más productivo durante el día.Apetencia por fumar", "Mantener una recámara fresca, con capacidad en la regulación de la luz y tan silenciosa como sea posible.", "Acostarte y levantarte a la misma hora todos los días, aun durante los fines de semana.", "Evitar pasar tiempo frente a dispositivos electrónicos que emanen luz (TV, teléfonos, computadora, tabletas, videojuegos, etc.), un par de horas previo al acostarse.", "Limitar el tiempo en cama.", "Utilizar la cama solo para dormir.", "Evitar la siesta prolongada (mayor a 30 MINUTOS) o especialmente poco antes de la hora de dormir.", "Si no concilias el sueño en 15 minutos o si te despierta y no se puede volver a dormir en ese tiempo, levántate y realice una actividad relajante con el mínimo de luz.", "Haz ejercicio regularmente, pero no cerca de la hora de dormir, es preferible la actividad cardiovascular por la mañana y/o una rutina de ejercicio en la tarde de acuerdo a su condición de salud.", "Evitar bebidas que contengan cafeína (café, algunos tés, chocolate y bebidas de cola) después de las 14:00hrs, o antes si se es sensible a la cafeína", "Evita el consumo de tabaco y alcohol.", "Evitar alimentos que provoquen agruras e indigestión y limitar la ingesta de líquidos antes de acostarse.", "Se recomienda la posición lateral si roncas.", "Realizar actividades de higiene como tomar un baño tibio y/o utilizar técnicas de relajación en un ambiente con luz tenue antes de acostarse."]
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ($("input[name=recomendacionesDescanso"+i+"]").is(":checked")) {
        var z = a[i];
        ax.push(z);
    }else{
        var y = a[i];
        ay.push(y);
        $('#lista1').append('<div><label>'+a[i]+'</label><br><input class="form-control" type="text" name="plandeacciones1_'+i+'" id="plandeacciones1_'+i+'"><br>');
    }
}
```

}

Lo que estaba planeando para validad cuantas palabras tienen los inputs es con el siguiente código:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    if (countWords($("#plandeacciones1_0").val()) > 5 && countWords($("#plandeacciones1_1").val()) > 5 ) {
        alert("yes");
    }else{
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Advertencia',
            text: 'Para poder avanzar, es necesario que respondas toda la información',
            icon: 'warning',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        });
    }
});
```

La función countWords realiza el conteo de palabras, pero en el ultimo código me estoy dando cuenta que si no existe algún input me da error, alguien me podría apoyar en esto por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al crear tus inputs, agrega en sus atributos una clase, y en el llamado de la función `countWords` agrega la validación de cuantos inputs de esa clase existen con la propiedad `getElementsByClassName()`  si es mayor a 0 el conteo, ejecutas el resto de `countWords`, se me ocurre esto, al crearlo añadi la clase `input_added`

```
$('#lista1').append('<div><label>'+a[i]+'</label><br><input class="form-control input_added" type="text" name="plandeacciones1_'+i+'" id="plandeacciones1_'+i+'"><br>');
```

Creo una variable que contenga todos los elementos de la clase `input_added`

```
var count_input = getElementsByClassName("input_added");
```

Y cuando llames a tu función `countWords` agrega la condición si `count_input` es mayor a 0 realiza el resto de tu función `countWords`

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    if (count_input.length > 0) {
        if (countWords($("#plandeacciones1_0").val()) > 5 && countWords($("#plandeacciones1_1").val()) > 5) {
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Advertencia',
                text: 'Para poder avanzar, es necesario que respondas toda la información',
                icon: 'warning',
                confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            });
        }
    }
    else { alert("El numero de inputs no es mayor a 0"); }
});
```